# Python music21 library create png from stream

Tags: python, music21, music-notation

I have a problem with generate png file from `stream` object in `music21`. I read documentation and I use `ConverterLilypond` to do this.

```
  chords = stream.Stream()

  d7 = chord.Chord(['D4', 'F4', 'A4', 'C5'])
  dmin7 = chord.Chord(['D4', 'F-4', 'A4', 'C5'])
  dmaj7 = chord.Chord(['D4', 'F#4', 'A4', 'C#5'])
  chords.append(d7)
  chords.append(dmin7)
  chords.append(dmaj7)
  conv = converter.subConverters.ConverterLilypond()
  conv.write(chords, fmt='lilypond', fp='file', subformats=['png'])
```

This code will generate png file, eps file count file, tex and texi file. Why? How can I generate only one file, PNG file?

When I try run this code in jupyter enough that I would use `chords.show()` to display image, but normally in the script the `show` generates a file, not a graphic.

EDIT:

Code with environment var

```
from music21 import *

us = environment.UserSettings()
us['lilypondPath'] = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/LilyPond/usr/bin/lilypond.exe'
us['musescoreDirectPNGPath'] = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/MuseScore 2/bin/MuseScore.exe'
us['musicxmlPath'] = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/MuseScore 2/bin/MuseScore.exe'

d7 = chord.Chord(['D4', 'F4', 'A4', 'C5'])

stream = stream.Stream()
stream.show('musicxml.png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best interface is by calling:

`chords.show('lily.png')`

which will run everything.  But the Lilypond interface is not so strong, so better would be to install MuseScore and set the MusescoreDirectPNGPath in `.music21rc` to point to the `mscore` executable and the just call `chords.show('musicxml.png')` and it will do a much better translation via `MusicXML`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm working on Windows where can I find `.music21rc`? I add `us['musescoreDirectPNGPath'] = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/MuseScore 2/bin/MuseScore.exe'
us['musicxmlPath'] = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/MuseScore 2/bin/MuseScore.exe'` in my script but this not working. Still the same error `cannot support showing in this format yet: png`

Comment: Bad me. Bad me. I should be pointing to the python interface for changing environment.UserSettings(). See http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/usersGuide/usersGuide_24_environment.html

Comment: And I think in some versions you should do show(‘musicxml.png’)

Comment: I do `stream.show('musicxml.png')` but it's show black screen in my default photo viewer. I put my code into question.

Comment: `music21.base.Music21ObjectException: cannot support showing in this format yet: lily.png`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to generated pngs from musicXML files this is the easiest way. And since you can export any music21 stream to musicxml this is a valid way to get PNGs.

If you have Musescore installed, then from the console you just type:

$ mscore3 -o myscore.png -r 300 myscore.xml

-r lets you specify the resolution in DPI

Answer (score -1):

For all those who will struggle with displaying scores from music21 within Jupyter Notebook on Linux (e.g. Ubuntu), follow these steps:

1) Install MuseScore (https://musescore.org/en/download), e.g. using snappy :

```
sudo snap install musescore
```

2) Locate musescore in your filesystem:

```
whereis musescore
```

In my case it is "`usr/bin/musescore`".

3) Set environmental variable to tell music21 how can it locate music21. Do it in your Jupyter Notebook:

```
environment.set("musescoreDirectPNGPath", "/usr/bin/musescore")
```

4) Now you can use musescore to render music scores from music21:

```
bwv295 = corpus.parse('bach/bwv295')
bwv295.show()
```

Comment: OP is asking how to generate a png output. Simply installing Musescore and calling `.show()` doesn't generate a png...

Comment: `environment.set()` is `music21.environment.set()` if you are like me confused where that came from.